# Approximating an element of a product sigma algebra by rectangles independent to a sub sigma algebra

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $(S,\mathcal{S},\mu)$ be a finite measure space and $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space. Denote the product space $(S\times \Omega, \mathcal{S} \times \mathcal{F},\mu \times \mathbb{P})$. Also let $\mathcal{G}$ denote a $\sigma$-algebra of $\Omega$.

Suppose $f: S \times \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a bounded measurable function. Suppose further that, for each $s \in S$, the random variable $f(s,\cdot)$ is independent of the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{G}$.

I am wondering if its possible to approximate $f^{-1}(B)$ for $B$ Borel by sets of the form $\left\{ U \times V   \right | U \in \mathcal{S}, V \in \mathcal{F} \ \mbox{and independent of} \ \mathcal{G}\}$. I know how to do this in $L^1$ without the independence condition.